# Three columns layout does not display correctly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to achieve a three column layout in one div in ASP.NET site but it only displays correctly in Firefox with Chrome displaying them underneath each other. I have the following asp.net code

```css
#container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#left {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
#middle {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
#right {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="left">
        <p>left column</p>
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
        <p>middle column</p>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <p>right column</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [**link**](https://i.gyazo.com/b41bb16e0af4efbc92ac9289a024046f.png) its showing up correctly on my chrome 49.

Comment: Looks right to me, too. You aren't showing any "asp.net code" except the runat attribute which is useless to us and most don't use asp.net anyway.

Comment: on my chrome 49 (64bit) too

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] of your problem. As of now, your code renders perfectly fine in Chrome (and any other browser, actually) so it means something else (which you have not yet included in your question) is affecting it on your server.

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't be using fixed widths in your `CSS` if you want your page to render decently on devices of all sizes. Here's [a responsive version](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/rjy7szkq/3/) of your code.

Comment: I forgot to link the page to the style sheet. That was the problem. Thank you guys